# Vectorizing across dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes i read from various csv files. Each data frame has the same format (ie. the columns are the same).

```
myList <- list(frame1, frame2, ..., frameN)
```

I often have to perform some computations on the corresponding columns in each dataframe, like summing all the salary columns in each dataframe for a given day (row).

```
day <- 1
dailyTotal <- NULL

for(i in 1:N){
    dailyTotal <- dailyTotal + myList[[i]]$Salary[day]
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better vectorized way of doing this without the for loop?

Comment: have you looked at `lapply`?

Comment: do your data.frames have the same number of rows? If so, creating a matrix of salaries (via `lapply` still) is what will give you access to a vectorized solution. And you will really start seeing a benefit if you are doing this for multiple values of `day`.

Comment: lappy, never heard of it, will look into it now. Yes each data frame has the same number of rows

Comment: @RJ,flodel Not sure what exactly you had in mind, but this is what I came up with sum(sapply(myList, function(x) x$Salary[day]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should consider rbinding your data frames into one large data frame on which you can then perform split-apply-combine style analysis.

Start by creating 5 data.frames in a list (with cols name and salary) to try to replicate your data:

```
dfs <- replicate(5, data.frame(name=sample(letters, 10), salary=runif(10, 50000,100000)), simplify=F)
```

Now `rbind` them into one large data frame, with an extra column `df.name` to inidicate the original data frame

```
dfs.bound <- do.call(rbind, mapply(cbind, df.name=paste("DF# ", 1:length(dfs)), dfs, SIMPLIFY=F)) 
str(dfs.bound)
# 'data.frame':  50 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ df.name: Factor w/ 5 levels "DF#  1","DF#  2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ name   : Factor w/ 21 levels "a","g","h","j",..: 5 2 4 10 8 1 9 6 3 7 ...
# $ salary : num  94666 74596 78793 77120 60251 ...
```

And split apply combine (showing three methods, `tapply` which works with just one column, and `plyr`/`data.table` which work with many):

```
tapply(dfs.bound$salary, dfs.bound$df.name, mean)
#   DF#  1   DF#  2   DF#  3   DF#  4   DF#  5  
# 74342.26 68222.44 71881.49 75840.18 63180.07
```

With `plyr` and `data.table` we can add more columns, and also different summarization statistics.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dfs.bound, "df.name", summarise, avg.salary=mean(salary), ppl.count=length(name))
#   df.name avg.salary ppl.count
# 1  DF#  1   74342.26        10
# 2  DF#  2   68222.44        10
# 3  DF#  3   71881.49        10
# 4  DF#  4   75840.18        10
# 5  DF#  5   63180.07        10
library(data.table)
data.table(dfs.bound)[, list(avg.salary=mean(salary), ppl.count=length(name)), by=df.name]
#    df.name avg.salary ppl.count
# 1:  DF#  1   74342.26        10
# 2:  DF#  2   68222.44        10
# 3:  DF#  3   71881.49        10
# 4:  DF#  4   75840.18        10
# 5:  DF#  5   63180.07        10
```

Answer (score 1):

There are pros and cons of keeping your data as a list vs. @BrodieG's method. It depends on what you want to do in other parts of your analysis etc. So here is the method while maintaining the data as a list:

```
# Create dummy data
list.of.data.frames <- lapply(1:10, function(n) data.frame(matrix(runif(100), nrow = 10)))

# Sum up X1 in each dataframe in the list
list.of.columnsums.of.x1 <- lapply(list.of.data.frames, function(n) sum(n[,"X1"]))

# Sum up the sums of X1 in each data.frame
sum.of.X1 <- do.call(sum, list.of.columnsums.of.x1)
```